# How do you classify current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, classical-electrodynamics

When talking about the electromagnetic field one usually thinks of:

- the **electric field** described locally by its intensity $\vec{E}$ and its flux density $\vec{D}$,
- the **magnetic field** described locally by its intensity $\vec{H}$ and its flux density $\vec{B}$.

There is however a fifth quantity: the electric current density $\vec{J}$. The first four quantities live together in pairs with each pair having its own designation. Poor little $\vec{J}$ seems to be all alone (no family) even though it has good ties with its friends:
\begin{equation}
    \vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \text{curl} \, \vec{H} = \vec{J} + \frac{\partial \vec{D}}{\partial t}
\end{equation}

My question is: *In which category should we place $\vec{J}$*? If $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{D}$ are electric and $\vec{H}$ and $\vec{B}$ are magnetic, what is $\vec{J}$?

It's obviously neither electric nor magnetic. Or maybe it's both. Is there an already established terminology for the field which "contains" $\vec{J}$?

Comment: What does it mean for a field to "contain" $\vec{J}$? You can express $\vec{J}$ in terms of the vector potential $\vec{A}$ in the Lorenz gauge. From there you can derive expressions relating $\vec{J}$ to the components of the electromagnetic field tensor-- but I'm not completely sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting of a major part of the story, the charge density $\rho$. The fields you are talking about, namely $\vec{E},\vec{D},\vec{B}$ and $\vec{H}$, are consequences of the configuration of electric sources in classical electrodynamics. These sources are the charge density $\rho$, and the current density $\vec{J}$, and both are electrical in nature, since they specify the configuration of electric charges and electric currents.